# max decomposition

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am looking to solve a problem of this form:

$\operatorname{argmax }_x\{f_1(x)-\operatorname{argmax}_yf_2(y)\}$

I am wondering if there any related math that we can decompose this onto something like $f_1$ or $f_2$ alone? (for instance, assume $f_1$ is convex and increasing function, etc

Comment: You should use a different dummy variable like $y$ for the inner $\arg\max$.

Comment: Is it $\arg\max_x\{f_1(x)-\arg\max_xf_2(x)\}$ or $\arg\max_x\{f_1(x)-f_2(x)\}$?

Comment: @trisct, former

Comment: @RobPratt, thx for the suggestion

Comment: In that case, you should rewrite it as $\arg\max_x\{f_1(x)-\arg\max_yf_2(y)\}$, then $\arg\max_yf_2(y)$ is just a constant to $f_1(x)$, which you can ignore because $\arg\max_xf_1(x)=\arg\max_x(f_1(x)+C)$.

Comment: You are just looking for $\operatorname{argmax} f_1$.